# what is wrong with my 'append' function?

Tags: prolog

I'm working on a simple Prolog example I saw in one of my classes, working with and re-implementing 'append'.  This is what I have (from the class):

```
append1([],L,L).
append1([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]) :-
    append1(L1,L2,L3).
```

When I do this, results in false:

```
append1([a,b],[c,d],L).
false.
```

But when I do this (with the built-in append), results in true:

```
append([a,b],[c,d],L).
true.
```

Why is there a difference?

And why do both of these following append examples even result in 'true'?  For some reason I expected to see a list of values for the Ls ...

```
append(L1,L2,[a,b,c]).
true.

append([a,b],[c,d],L).
true.
```

Comment: You haven't specified the relationship between `L3` and the inputs `L1`, and `L2`.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I left out a line in my question.  Fixed it.  Any other help is useful!

Comment: no, everything works as expected.

Comment: @WillNess I guess what I need is to learn is what append is actually doing.  I'm missing something.

Comment: I can offer you [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539203/how-do-i-append-lists-in-prolog/11551001#11551001). Do notice that you have a typo in `append1` - you call `append` inside it, instead of recursively calling `append1` itself.

Comment: You changed the definition of append/3. In case of doubt, do a `listing(appendl)` to see what Prolog actually got from you.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.1.33)
Copyright (c) 1990-2015 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam

?- [user].
append1([],L,L).
append1([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]) :-
   append1(L1,L2,L3).
^D
true.

?- append1([a,b],[c,d],L).
L = [a, b, c, d].
```

Note: The ^D is the ctrl character you need to press to
get out of [user] mode. You don't have to be in [user] mode 
to pose a query. Could be the error you were running into.

Bye