# Prolog: Putting elements in a list for a decimal to binary conversion

Tags: list, prolog

Hello I was trying to modify a decimal to binary conversion function, so that it would display the results in a list. I'm new to prolog and I can't seem to get it to function properly.

```
dec2bin(0,0).
dec2bin(1,1).
dec2bin(N,L):- N>1,X is N mod 2,Y is N//2,  dec2bin(Y,L1), L = [L1|[X]].
```

Then this is the result:

```
86 ?- dec2bin(26,L).
L = [[[[1, 1], 0], 1], 0]
```

Can someone help me understand what it is that I'm doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you amend your code

```
dec2bin(0,[0]).
dec2bin(1,[1]).
dec2bin(N,L):- 
    N > 1,
    X is N mod 2,
    Y is N // 2,  
    dec2bin(Y,L1),
    L = [X|L1].
```

you will get your solution with bits in reverse order:

```
?- dec2bin(26,L).
L = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Instead of appending each bit, consider a final reverse/2, or invert the order by means of an accumulator

```
dec2bin(N,L) :- dec2bin(N,[],L).

dec2bin(0,L,[0|L]).
dec2bin(1,L,[1|L]).
dec2bin(N,L,R):- 
    N > 1,
    X is N mod 2,
    Y is N // 2,  
    dec2bin(Y,[X|L],R).
```

Comment: I don't think that this clause is very usefull `dec2bin(0,L,[0|L])`.

Comment: @joel76, without that clause, or something to replace it, `dec2bin(0, L).` will fail.

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply some list concatenation, but you are just creating two terms lists and nesting them with `L = [L1|[X]]` when you consider `L1` to be just a number.

If you consider it as a list, you can simply appending to it the newly created `X`, but to do so you have to rewrite the base cases of your recursion:

```
dec2bin(0,[0]).
dec2bin(1,[1]).
dec2bin(N,L):- 
    N > 1,
    X is N mod 2,
    Y is N // 2,  
    dec2bin(Y,L1), 
    append(L1, [X], L).
```

yielding to:

```
?- dec2bin(26,L).
L = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

where `append/3` can be a [library predicate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3) or your own [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539203/how-do-i-append-lists-in-prolog).