# How do I return a specific list in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, append

I've written a small Prolog program that's supposed to check a list and see whether the head `Ha` is greater than `K`, if it is, it is supposed to append it to a list `R` and after checking the whole list give back `R` which then would consist of bigger than `K` integers.

This code returns `R = []`.

```
teilliste_grK([],_,_).

teilliste_grK([Ha|Ta], K, R) :-
    Ha =< K,
    teilliste_grK(Ta,K,R).

teilliste_grK([Ha|Ta], K, R) :-
    Ha > K,
    append(R, [Ha], C),
    teilliste_grK(Ta, K, C).
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write out how do you want to call this predicate with some sample data, and what you're expecting to get back from it. this is important. :)

okay, I'll do it: `teilliste_grK([1,4,2,5,3,6],3,X)` should succeed, instantiating `X` to `[4,5,6]`, correct? Now try to see which of the clauses does it match with.

So it matches with the second, `1` is indeed `=< 3`, and the last line says, continue without the head element (that was smaller than the given `K`), and *whatever `R` we get from there, is our `R` as well* – `R` is `R` after all.

Good. So when we come to `4` next, what happens? The 2nd clause matches but is then rejected with `4 =< 2`. Good. On to the third clause.

Again it matches, and the inequality holds, but then you do something strange. You first say that `C` is one element longer than `R`, and that `C` you get from the *shorter* list - the tail `Ta` of your input. Whatever you set your `R` in the final clause (the first one), this just can't be.

You want your `C` to be shorter than `R`, which is to start with the same head `Ha` which has just passed the test, so the arguments just need to be put in a different order:

```
    append([Ha], C, R),
```

(you can write this shorter and simpler though, without any call to `append` – what is it?).

Now what about that final (3rd, i.e. `[]`) clause? If you call `teilliste_grK([],3,X)`, what should `X` be?

Comment: I tried `append(R, Ha, R)` which is what I want but it wouldn't work. Problem is I'm quite new to Prolog and coming from Java which is mighty different. After the last call `X` should be the whole list which was appended through the recursive calls.

Comment: Ok, after implementing `append([Ha], C, R),` it works kinda but gives me an empty tail on the R-list, which is probably the case with my base call and I'll try to trace it. But I don't get the append order, I thought the first argument is the list to which I append the second argument and save it in the last argument.

Comment: Got the result I wanted with: `teilliste_grK([],_,R):- append([], R).` Though more through try and error then skill. What would be the simpler method without append?

Comment: [`append([], R)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2) appends together all lists inside its first argument - which is here empty, so the result is empty too: `R = []`. you can just write *that* instead. :)

Comment: You said I could write this `append([Ha], C, R),` shorter and without append, how? And thanks for the help by the way. While Prolog is simpler that's what making it difficult for me :)

Comment: about appending, see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11551001/849891) clarifies things. (disclaimer: that answer is by me also).