# Prolog returning true/false instead of variable

Tags: prolog

I'm working on the very easy reverse list example in Prolog.

```
append(A, [], [A]).
append(A, B, [A|B]).

reverse([], ReversedList).
reverse([A,B], ReversedList) :-
  reverse(B, TemporaryList),
  append(A, TemporaryList, ReversedList).
```

`append` works correctly. However, when I call `reverse` the interpreter doesn't respond with a variable like `append` but instead it just write true or false.

Here's the log:

```
1 ?- consult('capitolo2'.pl). % file containing the code
2 ?- append(a, [b,c,d], L).
L = [a,b,c,d]. % ok, this works
3 ?- reverse([a,b,c], L).
false. % what? why that's not L = something?
```

The platform is SWI-Prolog 7.2 on Windows

Comment: That's a rather non-standard definition of [`append`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3), usually `append` is defined to work on lists, e.g. `append([a,b,c], [x,y,z], L) ==> L = [a,b,c,x,y,z]`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539203/how-do-i-append-lists-in-prolog

Comment: It seems that's not the problem. If I rename `append` to `my_append` it's the same

Comment: You need to restart the Prolog system, too. Further there is `[A,B]` which should probably read `[A|B]` and much more...

Comment: Your `reverse` rule will only succeed if the first argument is an empty list (`[]`) or a two element list (`[A, B]`). It will fail all other cases since they won't match.

Comment: Why are you implementing a standard predicate like `append/3`? And if you have good reasons to do it, why do you not look it up once you run into problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`append/3`**

Did you *unit test* it? Did it work properly? Your `append/3` implementation is incorrect. The first clause

The first clause:

```
append( A , [] , [A]   ).
```

simply creates a list of length 1 from its 1st argument (whatever it might be). Given that, if you said:

```
append( [1,2,3] , [] , X ) .
```

You'd get back:

```
X = [ [1,2,3] ]
```

A list of length 1, with the sole item it contains being the original 1st argument. The second clause is similarly incorrect:

```
append( A , B , [A|B] ).
```

Prepends the 1st argument — whatever it might be, and **in its entirety** — as the head of that list. Given that, if you said something like:

```
append( [1,2,3] , [a,b,c] , X ) .
```

You'd get back:

```
X = [ [1,2,3] , a , b , c ] .
```

A list of length 4, the first item of which is the original 1st argument.

Prolog is a *descriptive language*: you *describe* the solution and let the engine work things out. `append/3` asserts that a list (the 3rd argument to `append/3` represent the concatenation of the 1st argument and the 2nd argument.

Here is an implementation of `append/3`, simplified for clarity:

```
append( []      , RL , RL ) .  % The concatenation of an empty left-hand list and a right hand list is the right hand list.
append( [LH|LT] , RL , CL ) :- % The concatenation of a non-empty left-hand list and a right-hand list is true IF:
  CL = [LH|CT] ,               % - The left-hand head and the concatenation head are the same, AND
  append( LT , RL , CT )       % - recursively, the concatenated tail represents the conconcatenation of the left-hand tail and the right-hand list.
  .                            % Easy!
```

As you pop items off the left-hand list, it will eventually decompose into the terminating special case. This can be simplified to the classic implementation:

```
append( []      , RL , RL      ) .
append( [LH|LT] , RL , [LH|CT] ) :- append( LT , RL , CT ) .
```

**`reverse/3`**

Similarly, your `reverse/3` implemenation is incorrect. Your first clause:

```
reverse([], ReversedList).
```

pretty much says that pretty much anything is the reverse of the empty list. Since your `ReversedList` variable is never referenced, your Prolog implementation should at least throw a warning about singleton variables here. Many implementations make it an error.

Your second clause:

```
reverse([A,B], ReversedList) :-
  reverse(B, TemporaryList),
  append(A, TemporaryList, ReversedList).
```

says that the reverse of a 2-item list (`[A,B]`) is obtained by

- reversing the 2nd *item* in the list (`B`), and
- appending the 1st item (`A`) to that.

Not exactly a correct description of the solution. You might try something like

```
reverse( []    , [] ) .  % The empty list is already reversed, what with it being atomic and all.
reverse( [H|T] , R  ) :- % a non-empty list can be reversed by decomposing it into its head and tail, and
  reverse(T,T1) ,        % - reversing the tail, and
  append(T1,H,R) .       % - appending the head to the now-reversed tail.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it was just a syntax problem. I wanted to write reverse([A|B], ReversedList) insted of reverse([A,B], ReversedList). It still doesn't work but I knew the algorithm wasn't ok.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible there are other problems, but

1. ```
   reverse([], ReversedList).
   ```

   is almost surely not what you want here. The reverse of an empty list is an empty list, translates to

   ```
   reverse([], []).
   ```
2. Additionally,

   ```
   reverse([A,B], ReversedList)
   ```

   is also probably not what you want. It is *not* a list with head A and tail B, but rather a 2-element list.

Comment: The result is the same :(

Comment: That was the problem (nr2). Now it doesn't return me the corrent result, but that's a problem in my algorithm