# Need explanation on this SWI Prolog bubble sort coding

Tags: prolog, append, bubble-sort

Need to know what are these `L1`, `[H1 | L2]`. No idea at all.

```erlang
bubSort([],[]) :- !.
bubSort([H],[H]) :- !.
bubSort(L,SL) :- append(L1, [H1,H2|L2], L), H2 < H1, append(L1, [H2,H1|L2], NL), !,
                 bubSort(NL,SL).
bubSort(L,L).
```

This compiles and sorts the list well. But I need to understand this mechanism.
Specially the how this `append` works.

Comment: Explanation about what? The bubble sort algorithm? It is well explained elsewhere. `append` predicate? It is in the documentation of SWI Prolog.

Comment: `append(A, B, C)` means `B` appended to `A` is `C`. Or equivalently, `A` concatenated with `B` is `C`.

Comment: Need to know what are these L1, [H1 | L2]. No idea at all

Comment: You need to go learn some very fundamental Prolog evidently. Book or tutorial. `L1` is just a variable. Used in `append`, it represents a list since `append` operates on lists. `[H1|L2]` is a Prolog list with head `H1` and tail `L2`.

Comment: was my answer helpful? do you have any more questions or concerns?

Answer (score 1):

- `L1` : a logical variable (the name suggestive of a "list")
- `L1 = [H1 | L2]` : the list `L1` has `H1` as its head element, and `L2` is a list of all the rest of its elements
- `append(L1, [H1,H2|L2], L)` : the list `L` consists of the elements of a list `L1`, then the element `H1`, then the element `H2`, and the elements of the list `L2` after that
- `H2 < H1` : an arithmetical value referred to by the logical variable `H2` is smaller in magnitude than the arithmetical value referred to by the logical variable `H1`
- `append(L1, [H2,H1|L2], NL)` : the list `NL` consists of the elements of a list `L1`, then the element `H2`, then the element `H1`, and the elements of the list `L2` after that
- `bubSort([],[]) :- !.` *bubSort* of an empty list `[]` is an empty list, `[]`
- `bubSort([H],[H]) :- !.` *bubSort* of a singleton list `[H]` (a list with just one element, `H`, in it) is a singleton list `[H]`, i.e. the same list
- `bubSort(L,SL) :- append(L1, [H1,H2|L2], L), H2 < H1, append(L1, [H2,H1|L2], NL), !, bubSort(NL,SL).` : *bubSort* of a list, call it `L`, is a list, call it `SL` (for "sorted list"), such that there exist two adjacent elements in `L` which are out of order, the list `NL` is exactly the same as `L` just with those two adjacent elements swapped, and the *bubSort* of `NL` is `SL`
- `bubSort(L,L).` : finally, if there's no two adjacent elements which are out of order, *bubSort* of such  list is the list itself.

see also: [How do I append lists in prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539203/how-do-i-append-lists-in-prolog/11551001#11551001)