# Conver from hex to binary in Prolog

Tags: binary, prolog, hex, converters

Here is some program for converting hex to binary, and I need to get in the result something like `X = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]` for `pred([f,0])`.

So I need to join all lists in one. Can someone show me how to do it?

```
hex(0, [0,0,0,0]).
hex(1, [0,0,0,1]).
hex(2, [0,0,1,0]).
hex(3, [0,0,1,1]).
hex(4, [0,1,0,0]).
hex(5, [0,1,0,1]).
hex(6, [0,1,1,0]).
hex(7, [0,1,1,1]).
hex(8, [1,0,0,0]).
hex(9, [1,0,0,1]).
hex(a, [1,0,1,0]).
hex(b, [1,0,1,1]).
hex(c, [1,1,0,0]).
hex(d, [1,1,0,1]).
hex(e, [1,1,1,0]).
hex(f, [1,1,1,1]).

pred([],X).

pred([H|T],X):-
 hex(H,Y),
 append(X,Y,X),
 write(Y),
 nl,
 pred(T).
```

My problem is in append.

Comment: `append(X,Y,X)` says X is the result of X appended to Y. This could only ever be true if Y were empty. This tells me you think you can change the value of a variable in Prolog, but you cannot, you need another variable here. Also, intermixing of output with your logic is going to hurt you in the long run. I would recommend you consult a tutorial! You can't wing it in Prolog.

Comment: see [How do I append lists in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11539203/849891), make sure you understand how `append` works with lists in a top-down manner. it applies here as well. not with your 'append' line, but with the `pred` predicate itself. `pred` will instantiate its binary list in the top-down manner, too.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with some examples, pretending we already have this predicate:

```
?- pred( [f, 0],  X ).
X = [1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0].        % that's what you said you want, isn't it?

?- pred( [f, 0],  [1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0] ).
yes.

?- pred( [f | [0]],  [1,1,1,1 | [0,0,0,0]] ).
yes.

?- pred( [f | HEX], [A,B,C,D | BIN] ),  [A,B,C,D] = [1,1,1,1],  pred( HEX, BIN).
yes.

?- pred( [f | HEX], [A,B,C,D | BIN] ),  hex(f, [A,B,C,D]),  pred( HEX, BIN). 
yes.

?- pred( [0 | HEX2], [A2,B2,C2,D2 | BIN2] ),  hex(0, [A2,B2,C2,D2]),  pred( HEX2, BIN2). 
yes.

?- pred( [0 | HEX2], [A2,B2,C2,D2 | BIN2] ),  hex(0, [A2,B2,C2,D2]),  
                                               HEX2 = [], BIN2 = [],  pred( HEX2, BIN2). 
yes.
```

Yes? Right? (In case it isn't clear, consider the identity `[0] = [0 | []]`).

This means it must also be the case that

```
?- HEX2 = [], BIN2 = [],  pred( HEX2, BIN2). 
yes.

?- pred( [], []). 
yes.
```

Voila, we see what the base case *must* be. Right?

Moreover, we actually have seen there what the *recursive* case must be, as well. And you don't need any explicit `append` calling there. This:

```
?- pred( [f | HEX], [A,B,C,D | BIN] ),  hex(f, [A,B,C,D]),  pred( HEX, BIN). 
yes.
```

can be written as

```
?- pred( [F | HEX], [A,B,C,D | BIN] ),  F = f, hex(F, [A,B,C,D]),  pred( HEX, BIN). 
yes.
```

but actually, it is *easily* generalized to

```
?- pred( [F | HEX], [A,B,C,D | BIN] ),  hex(F, [A,B,C,D]),  pred( HEX, BIN). 
yes.
```

And there you have it.

See? Prolog is *fun*. Prolog is *easy*. Prolog is *just saying what you mean*.