# How prolog derivation works in this query?

Tags: list, prolog, concatenation, trace

I tried to write a simple Prolog program with the following ruleset.

```pl
conc([],L,L).
conc([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]):- conc(L1,L2,L3).
```

Then I loaded this in the SWI-Prolog shell and executed the following query in the trace mode.

```pl
 ?-conc([2,3],[p,q],[2,3,p,q]).
```

The output was as follows.

```pl
[trace]  ?- conc([2,3],[p,q],[2,3,p,q]).
   Call: (8) conc([2, 3], [p, q], [2, 3, p, q]) ? creep
   Call: (9) conc([3], [p, q], [3, p, q]) ? creep
   Call: (10) conc([], [p, q], [p, q]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) conc([], [p, q], [p, q]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) conc([3], [p, q], [3, p, q]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) conc([2, 3], [p, q], [2, 3, p, q]) ? creep
true.
```

Now the problem is to draw the derivation tree of this goal, but I can't exactly understand how prolog does this, even by looking at the `trace`  output above.

Can someone explain the derivation tree of the above query with regard to the mentioned ruleset? Helpful answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: see also: [How do I append lists in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11539203/849891).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivation tree is the following (considering clauses with renamed variables):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
?- conc([2,3],[p,q],[2,3,p,q]).

Call: (8) conc([2, 3], [p, q], [2, 3, p, q]) ? creep
```

The current goal is the question.

Since `[2,3]` does not match `[]`, rule 1 is no option, thus rule 2 is tried.
To match the head of rule 2, these substitutions are made: `X/2, L1/[3], L2/[p,q], L3/[3,p,q]`.

Our new goal is now the body of rule 2, `conc(L1,L2,L3)`, after the substitutions above, that is `conc([3],[p,q],[3,p,q])`.

```
Call: (9) conc([3], [p, q], [3, p, q]) ? creep
```

Since `[3]` does not match `[]`, rule 1 is no option, thus rule 2 is tried.
Substitutions: X/3, L1/[], L2/[p,q], L3/[p,q]
Our new goal is now conc(L1,L2,L3) after the appropriate solutions, which amounts to `conc([],[p,q],[p,q])`.

```
Call: (10) conc([], [p, q], [p, q]) ? creep
```

Matches rule 1 => proof suceeded

Thus, the to-do-list for goal 10 is proven, thus goal 10 is proven:

```
Exit: (10) conc([], [p, q], [p, q]) ? creep
```

Thus, the to-do-list for goal 9 is proven, thus goal 9 is proven:

```
Exit: (9) conc([3], [p, q], [3, p, q]) ? creep
```

Thus, the to-do-list for goal 8 is proven, thus goal 8 is proven:

```
Exit: (8) conc([2, 3], [p, q], [2, 3, p, q]) ? creep
```

Since goal8 was the question, we're done, the proof is complete:

```
true.
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel that using the tracer is generally unhelpful unless you already know what you are doing and know that there is a problem at a precise location and even then it's a *hard-to-disentangle* *mess*.

It's much better to look closely at the program, and read it as the definition of a recursive call (or alternatively, as an inductive definition):

1. The concatenation of an *empty* list `[]` and some other list `L` is that same list `L`:

```
    conc( [], L, L ).
```

2. The concatenation of a *nonempty* list whose first element is `X` and some other list `L2` is a list which is starting with that same `X` and continuing with a list `L3` *such that:*

   - `L3` is the concatenation of lists `L1` and `L2`:

```
    conc( [X | L1], L2, [X | L3] ) :- 
        conc(  L1,  L2,      L3 ).
```

This is a pretty good actionable definition of concatenation:

- Whenever a `conc(A1,A2,R)` succeeds, then we certainly have that all the element of `A1` followed by all the elements of `A2` form `R` (and so the definition makes sense as "concatenation").
- Whenever `conc` "refers to itself" (recursively) the first list argument is smaller by one, so we have a "variant" that is monotonically decreasing and are getting somewhere (we will also automatically stop because a list length is always >= 0).
- There is a non-recursive definition for a "base case" to be applied when the first list argument is of length 0, so when we stop, we can do so successfully (if the first clause `conc([],L,L).` was missing we would stop but fail due to lack of a matching clause for an empty list).

The "derivation tree" is rather linear (and not different from a derivation that you would find in a functional language), i.e. apply the second clause recurisvely until it no longer applies, then apply he first clause.

And thus we see:

```
Call: (8) conc([2, 3], [p, q], [2, 3, p, q])
   Call: (9) conc([3], [p, q], [3, p, q])
      Call: (10) conc([], [p, q], [p, q])
      Exit: (10) conc([], [p, q], [p, q])
   Exit: (9) conc([3], [p, q], [3, p, q])
Exit: (8) conc([2, 3], [p, q], [2, 3, p, q])
```

Note the traditional name of the "Exit port". The correct name is and should have always been "Success", even back in the 1980s. It never got changed.

Comment: I guess one thing `exit` got going for it is that is has the same number of letters in it as `call`. :)