# Prolog list concat

Tags: prolog

I am learning Prolog and I have stumbled upon this piece of code and I cannot make sense of it:

Code:

```
append([],Ys,Ys). 

append([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]):- 
            append(Xs, Ys, Zs).
```

In the example, the instruction given is:

Code:

```
append([1,2],[3,4],Ys).
```

and the output is `Ys = [1,2,3,4]`

And I don't understand how that happens.

I understand that the values on Xs get removed one by one until it equals [], what I don't understand is 
1. Why is Zs being changed; if the fact is `append([],Ys,Ys)`, `Zs` should be equal to `[3,4]` so why changing it in any way if it already obeys the fact?
2. How do `[1,2]` get in the beginning of `Zs`??

I used trace and the result of that is even more confuse, because `Zs` is always values like `_G5166`, `_G5112`, etc... 
What are those values? Are those memory addresses?

And why is it that, even if I don't use write(), the console displays `Ys = ...`? And why `Ys` and not `Xs` or `Zs`?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539203/how-do-i-append-lists-in-prolog, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620011/explanation-of-a-prolog-algorithm .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first pair of questions:

1. It's not the same `Zs`. Initially, when you try `append([1,2],[3,4],Ys).`, then Prolog says to itself "Hmm, I could do that if the original `Ys` were in the form `[X|Zs]`, and now I just need to match `append(Xs, Ys, Zs).`" The next time it says "Hmm, I could do that if the original `Zs` were in the form `[X|OhterZs]`, and now I just need to match `append(Xs, Ys, OtherZs).`" Just imagine that with eacy recursion call, it's making new variable names.
2. The 1 and 2 get to the front through the first two invocations, *each one to its own version of `Zs`*.

Regarding your other points:

- The strange thingies that are trace are exactly these recursion-local `Zs`
- Since your query was `append([1,2],[3,4],Ys).`, and `Ys` was the only variable, then Prolog interprets your query as asking what match of `Ys` would evaluate truthfully.