# Checking if two concatenated lists are equal to a third list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

So i have this predicate that has to succeed when `L` is the concatenation of the other two lists, `X` and `Y`. Apparently it doesn't work yet. The question is how could i fix the code fragment. Being new to Prolog i still am not sure how can i implement this correctly, having worked only with procedural programming until now.

```
% concat(L,X,Y) returns true if L is the concatenation of the lists X and Y

concat([],L,L).
concat([X1|L1],L2,[X1|L3]) :- concat(L1, L2, L3).
```

Comment: It seems that you concatenate `L` and `X` with your current code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620011/explanation-of-a-prolog-algorithm-to-append-two-lists-together?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa