# How is suffix/prefix working internally in prolog?

Tags: prolog

Can anyone explain how prolog finds a `suffix(L1,L2)` or `prefix(L1,L2)` internally?
I know the rule is `suffix(L1,L2):- append(_,L2,L1).`
But, I can't seem to understand how the variables `_`, `L1` and `L2` going inside append and working the query out?

```
append([],X,X).
append([H|T],Y, [H|W]):- append(T,Y, W).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [understand `append`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539203/how-do-i-append-lists-in-prolog/11551001#11551001), then the definition

```erlang
suffix( A, B) :- append( _X, B, A).
```

is ... well, actually, what *is* the meaning of `append( X, B, A)`?

It's that (in *pseudocode*) `[...X, ...B] == A`: the list of elements of `X`, followed by elements of `B`, together, is the list of elements in `A`.

This means that `B` is a (suffix / prefix -- make a choice, please) of `A`, right? and we don't care what `X` is. In particular it can be empty, or not.

This explains `suffix`. For `append` please see the linked answer, and the [answer *it* links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620011/explanation-of-a-prolog-algorithm-to-append-two-lists-together/10620282#10620282).

This gives us an idea for a follow up question:

- Define the predicate `proper_suffix(A, B)` such that "proper_suffix of A is B" holds, i.e. `B` is a suffix of `A`, and `B` is not the same as `A`.

---

You write

> I am not understanding how `_` for the suffix's argument is going inside `append([H|T], Y, [H|W]):- append(T,Y, W)`. How is `append` processing the `_` for the `H` of the `append` to find whether `L2` is suffix of `L1`? if I pass `_`, how does Prolog figure out the `H` and `T`, coz by anonymous variable we mean that *'we don't care about its value'* .

So we have

```erlang
suffix(        A, B) :- 
   append( _X,    B,
               A).
```

Whatever the `A` and `B` were in the call to `suffix(A, B)`, they will be the same in the call to `append( _X, B, A)`. When that call returns with logic variables `_X`, `A` and `B` holding their (possibly updated) values, the call to `suffix` returns with *its* `A` and `B` holding those same values as in the `append` call. The value of `_X` is not made use of by the `suffix/2` predicate, but it *is* found out just the same, by `append/3`.

You seem to be confused about the anonymous variable, `_`. It doesn't matter that it is named that way, it is still a variable. Forget the "don't care" thing, it is confusing and imprecise. Imagine it is named `_X`, as I showed. it will work exactly the same with `_Y`, `_`, `Abracadabra`, etc., as long as it is *not the same* as the other variables' names in that rule.

Just one caveat: without the leading `_` Prolog will warn us about "singleton variable" i.e. a variable that isn't used anywhere else. It is with respect to *this* that we signal our intention that "we don't care", with the (leading) `_`.

Its value is still going to be found, as usual!

And when we use `_`, the additional convenience is that we don't have to make sure that the name is unique. Each `_` is treated as if it were unique, automatically.

---

You ask (in the comments) how does the query `append(_X, [a,b], [1,2,a,b])` work.

Prolog works by choosing a rule whose head  *matches* the query.

This query matches the second clause's head:

```erlang
append(_X, [a,b], [1,2,a,b]) = append([H|T], Y, [H|W])
```

with

```erlang
_X = [H|T], Y = [a,b], [H|W] = [1,2,a,b]
```

Which also means

```erlang
H = 1, W = [2,a,b],
```

*and hence*

```erlang
_X = [H|T] = [1|T]
```

See? This doesn't *deconstruct* `_X`, it *builds it up!*

Since its head matches the query, the *second* clause of your `append` definition is thus *chosen*, and so its body is fired up as the *new* query under the same *substitution*, i.e. set of "assignments" to the logic variables involved. So it calls

```erlang
_X = [H|T], Y = [a,b], [H|W] = [1,2,a,b], append(T,Y,W).
```

as the new query. That is,

```erlang
_X = [1|T], Y = [a,b], W = [2,a,b], append(T,Y,W).    %% or,
_X = [1|T1], append(T1, [a,b], [2,a,b]).
```

If we apply the same reasoning, we see again the second clause matching up, and  end up with

```erlang
_X = [1|T1], T1 = [2|T2], append(T2, [a,b], [a,b]).
```

But now the *first* clause matches,

```erlang
append(T2, [a,b], [a,b]) = append([],X,X)
```

which entails

```erlang
T2 = [].
```

Thus

```erlang
_X = [1|T1]
        T1 = [2|T2]
                T2 = [].
```

The list now held by `_X` has thus been built in a top-down fashion.

Comment: I get your point, I understood suffix after looking at the code but I wanted to trace the code as prolog does, I am not understanding how _ for the suffix's argument is going inside append([H|T], Y, [H|W]):- append(T,Y, W).
How is append processing the _ for the H of the append to find whether L2 is suffix of L1? if I pass _, how does prolog figure out the H and T, cz by anonymous variable we mean that 'we don't care about its value' .

Comment: @zena have you looked at the linked answers though? one gives declarative overview, the other gives exactly the kind of operational run down you ask about.  I'll see if I can add some clarifications here, but I'm positive studying those answers will help clear things up for you. don't hesitate to ask more. :)

Comment: the append will take on the passed value _ , L2,L1 and work with _ as a normal variable, and you know append needs to know the list passed on as _ in order for L2 to be added at the end of that list denoted by _ , so how is it doing that, by
append(_ , [a,b], [1|2,a,b]):- append(T, [a,b], [2,a,b]).
so it's figuring out the T which is 2 by looking at [1|2,a,b] since a,b is L2 that means the H is 1 and T is 2 for the list denoted by _ ? I hope I could make you understand my problem.