# How is the unbound output list bound to the input list elements plus 1 for each?

Tags: prolog

This is the command that calls the procedure `add1`:

`listmanager::add1([1,2,3,4], NewList)`,

please note the `NewList` variable is unbound.

The following `add1` procedure adds *1* to each element of the input list `[1,2,3,4]`. It stores the information in the output list `NewList`.

clauses:

```cpp
add1([], []).            /* boundary condition */
add1([Head|Tail], [NewHead|NewTail]):- 
    /* separate the head from the rest of the list */
    NewHead = Head+1,    /* add 1 to the first element */
    add1(Tail, NewTail). /* call element with the rest of the list */
```

There is no explicit assignment of `NewTail` and `NewHead` to the output list.

I ran this code through the debugger. It works. The head of the input list is bound and *1* *is* added. In the last step, `add1([],[])`, the output list has all the elements *+1* of the input list.

How?

Comment: cf. a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10620282/849891)

Answer (score 1):

> There is no explicit assignment of `NewTail` and `NewHead` to the output list.

There are no assignments at all, Prolog uses *unification*. This is important, because unification plays the role of both analyzing *existing* data structures and building *new ones*. This is different from programming languages that have assignments.

It is also important to know that putting terms inside a clause head is an implicit unification. So this:

```
add1([Head|Tail],[NewHead|NewTail]) :-
    ...
```

is equivalent to this:

```
add1(List1, List2):-
    List1 = [Head | Tail],
    List2 = [NewHead | NewTail],
    ...
```

(But the first form can sometimes be executed more efficiently.)

Now, for the two roles of unification, consider this predicate:

```
list_head_tail([Head | Tail], Head, Tail).
```

which can also be written as:

```
list_head_tail(List, Head, Tail) :-
    List = [Head | Tail].
```

Due to the properties of unification, this can work in different ways. We can use it to "construct" a list:

```
?- list_head_tail(List, a, [b, c]).
List = [a, b, c].
```

but also to "deconstruct" an existing list:

```
?- List = [1, 2, 3], list_head_tail(List, Head, Tail).
List = [1, 2, 3],
Head = 1,
Tail = [2, 3].
```

Note that this binds `Head` and `Tail` to values even though "there is no explicit assignment" of either of these variables in the body of `list_head_tail/3` predicate. Unification can bind variables to values in this way.

So to answer your question, when you call `add1([1, 2, 3, 4], NewList)` the following things happen to `NewList`:

1. it is unified with `[NewHead | NewTail]`
2. `NewHead` is unified with a new value; if you use `is` for arithmetic, `NewHead` is unified with `2`, so the value of `NewList` is now `[2 | NewTail]`
3. in the recursive call to `add1`, `NewTail` is unified with a new term `[NewHead2 | NewTail2]` (I'm using *renamed (freshly named) variables* here as Prolog itself in effect does)
4. `NewHead2` is unified with `3`, so your outermost (or topmost) `NewList` is now `[2 | [3 | NewTail2]]` = `[2, 3 | NewTail2]`
5. some more recursive calls to `add1` happen, progressively setting up `NewHead3` and `NewTail3`, `NewHead4` and `NewTail4`, etc. -- I'll skip them here
6. in the final recursive call, the last `NewTail_n` variable is unified with `[]` and the chain of `add1` calls is thus finished
7. at this point `NewList = [2 | [3 | [4 | [5 | []]]]]`, constructed "from the outside in" (i.e. *top-down*); this term is equivalent to the more readable syntax `[2, 3, 4, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

That is because in Prolog `1+1` is just `1+1` (or more canonical `+(1,1)`), not `2`. You can use [**`is/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2) to *evaluate* a numerical expression, so:

```
add1([], []).
add1([Head|Tail],[NewHead|NewTail]):-
    NewHead is Head+1,
    add1(Tail, NewTail).
```

You can furthermore make use of [**`maplist/3`**](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3) to perform a mapping:

```
inc(X, Y) :-
    Y is X+1.

add1(L, R) :-
    maplist(inc, L, R).
```

Comment: There is no question about adding 1 to each element. The question is NewTail  is not assigned. How is it getting bound to the elements + 1 from the input list?  Looad at the second lin add1([Head|Tail], [NewHead|NewTail]) :-   .... Head and Tail are assigned from the list[ [1,2,3,4]. Where is {NewHead|NewTail getting bound?

Comment: @Irongrinder: `NewTail` is grounded by the recursive call in `add1`, it will keep unifying it with a new "cons" until it fires `add1([],[])`, when it will be unfied with `[]`.